# Access to the path 'logs' folder is denied

Tags: permissions, logs

I am getting the following error in my dev machine. the log files folder has not been changed from the default location.

```
Completed processing of timer job [job-usage-log-file-import] with lock type [None] against target instance [16edfc16-d399-470c-b194-0ef6005fec5e] [SPServer Name=SP-DEV-02]. Start time: [10/24/2019 07:40:41]. Duration: [00:00:00.9687241]. Status result: [Failed]. Status ressage (if any): [Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS\FeatureUsage\ImportProgress.ini' is denied.. (Correlation=2bee109f-b1bd-502e-fec5-e4efd2e29985)].

The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsageImportJobDefinition (ID 0dcaf758-54cc-45eb-9675-7ce52f366a19) threw an exception. More information is included below.  Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS\RequestUsage\ImportProgress.ini' is denied.. (Correlation=99ef109f-61e3-502e-fec5-ef584f065bd0)
```

**edit**: I can open the logs via explorer and even via the ULS Viewer, but logs are displaying the error above.

**Configure usage and health data collection** log path:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS\
```

**Diagnostic Logging** logs path:

```
%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS\
```

They correspond with the log folder 16 hive.

what could be the reason?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Check if you have access to the hive by visiting the logs through explorer

Comment: I have access to the logs folder and I can open the logs via the ULS viewer. I have give everyone access to the logs folder, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Running `Initialize-SPResourceSecurity` should properly set the ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, `Central Administration/Monitoring/Configure Diagnostic Logging/Path`
[image]

Go to `Configure diagnostic logging -> path`. Check if the path matches your logs folder path.

Also check in Configure usage and health data collection. It will have the `Log File Location` setting.

If everything is fine, then add `SharePoint Timer Service Account` into
the local administrators group of SharePoint server and try again.

Comment: yes, they correspond and the path is correct. it points to logs folder in 16 hive.